# Undefined method `authenticates_with_sorcery!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sorcery

I just performed a basic installation of Sorcery. When I try to load the signup page I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Gemfile

```
# Authentication
gem 'sorcery', git: 'https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery'
```

I'm using rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.0.0

Comment: Might seem too simple, but did you remember to bundle install?

Comment: Yep. And migrated the db.

Comment: I forgot the restart my server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restart the server after bundle installing.